# Aspect ratio of image components in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to break an image into components.This is my image-
[image]

This is the code-

```
image=imread('compo1.jpg'); 
image=imresize(image,[394 464]);
image = im2bw(image);
image=imcomplement(image);   

[imx imy]=size(image);
new1=zeros(imx,imy);
compo = bwlabel(image,8) ;
mx=max(max(compo));

for i=1:mx
    [r,c] = find(compo==i);
    new1=zeros(imx,imy);
    rc = [r c];
    [sx sy]=size(rc);


    for j=1:sx
        x1=rc(j,1);
        y1=rc(j,2);
        new1(x1,y1)=1;
    end
    imshow(new1);
    s = regionprops(new1, 'BoundingBox' );
    A =(s.BoundingBox(4) / s.BoundingBox(3))
end
```

I am using `bwlabel` but here my image has a single connected component,so its not working.I want to separate out each line as separate segments.My main objective is to find aspect ratio of each line segments.How can I do this without using `bwlabel` ?

Comment: You can't with `bwlabel` as it is one single conneted component. What if you identify all the lines first with e.g Hough transform and then work out the segments by looking at the crossings or something...

Comment: I would suggest you to try to taking partial derivatives on image using different masks. First step can be separating vertical horizontal and diagonal components(using different masks). Second step can be done using simple edge detection. This is an idea, try to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hough Transform to detect lines, however the output will be in parametric form. So you can go for convolution techniques where a kernel intended for a specific orientation is convoluted with the image to get the line in that particular direction. You can refer this [link](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/linedet.htm) for more detailed description.